# Ansible filters (ipaddr) in Python

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I am trying to use ansible filter (ipaddr) in python.

```
from ansible.plugins.filter import ipaddr
import jinja2

env = jinja2.Environment()
tmpl_string = """test : {{ '10.124.0.0'| ipaddr(-1) }}"""
tmpl = env.from_string(tmpl_string)
print(tmpl.render())
```

I am able to import the ipaddr filter with not any issues but when I am executing the code I am receiving following error:

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateAssertionError: No filter named 'ipaddr'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a filter with Jinja in order to make it available in templates; see the [Custom Filters](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#writing-filters) section of the documentation. You want:

```
from ansible.plugins.filter import ipaddr
import jinja2

env = jinja2.Environment()

# tell jinja about the ipaddr filter
env.filters['ipaddr'] = ipaddr

tmpl_string = """test : {{ '10.124.0.0'| ipaddr(-1) }}"""
tmpl = env.from_string(tmpl_string)
print(tmpl.render())
```

Comment: (Also note that you need to have the `netaddr` module installed for the `ipaddr` filter to work correctly.)

Comment: answer is correct. But note with more recent versions of Ansible you need to import ipaddr like this instead:
```
from ansible_collections.ansible.netcommon.plugins.filter.ipaddr import ipaddr
```

Comment: How would it be possible to add b64encode filter using the same syntax? I cannot find the corresponding collection over the form <from ansible_collections.ansible..... import ....>

Comment: Ansible incudes `b64encode` and `b64decode` filters by default. `from ansible.plugins.filter.core import b64encode`, and then proceed as above. If you have more questions this topic, please open a new question.